# -[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, xcode5

Hi All i have implement the google maps sdk on my application and i am getting an error on this particular line 
 mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
Can any one help me to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please mention which version of iOS you are using and did you setted delegate method for MAPview.

Please check the below link, may be helps you, all the best

[GoogleMaps basic iOS demo app crash - unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019776/googlemaps-basic-ios-demo-app-crash-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you remove the **-ObjC linker flag** from your target. Once you **put this flag back** the application will not crash.

If you have removed this flag because you are using parse SDK as well and its not allowing you to compile your project with too many linking errors, the workaround is that you have to remove the Facebook related parse sdks from your project.

**Thus the bottom line is if you want to use both Google Map and Parse SDK you have to remove the Parse's Facebook SDK and -ObjC linker flag must be set for Other Linker Flags.**

Answer (score -1):

Developing an application with the Google Maps SDK for iOS requires the following:

Xcode 4.5 or later.
iOS SDK 6.0 or later.