# Can't get Google Maps to initialize Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
var camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6); 
var gmaps: GMSMapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera);

gmaps.myLocationEnabled = true

gmaps.delegate = self

self.view=gmaps
```

I got this error :

> 2014-08-15 17:22:43.749 MapTest[1579:60b] -[GMSMapView
>   animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x17dbf550
>
> 2014-08-15 17:22:43.756 MapTest[1579:60b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView
>   animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x17dbf550'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reproduced the problem of an unrecognised selector being sent to my instance by taking the -ObjC linker flag out of my working Google Maps Swift project. Although mine was for a different selector, I'd still guess that the answer for Swift is the same as earlier answers for Objective C code. Make sure to follow this step of [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) carefully, setting the flag on the Project, not the individual target:

> Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab.
>   In the Other Linker Flags section, add `-ObjC`. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All.

(If that's not the problem, did you check through [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019776/googlemaps-basic-ios-demo-app-crash-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572311/gmsmapview-animatetocameraposition-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170851/google-maps-animatetocameraposition-ios7-issue) on the subject? If so, which of those answers have you tried?)

Answer (score 2):

Setting flag on the project, rather than a specific target causes this error.
Take a look inside GoogleMapsSDKDemos Project Settings to see that flag is set **on the target rather then the project**