# Swift/GMaps - keep getting an error

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

Please note - I have checked through SO for an answer to this.  Many developers have answered, however I feel I have done what was needed.

I added the -ObjC to the project: Other Linker Flags.

I keep getting this error:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView
>   animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have followed Googles steps - step by step as well as watching a number of videos (which are in ObjC) and reading a number of blogs.

I have added all frameworks and even unticked do not copy when adding the GMaps bundle.

Here is my code.

AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


       Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
       Parse.setApplicationId("ParseKey_eOHadu2GEOBqxvRl8ijKM0PMhq3", clientKey: "ParseKey_yFjq2MWocV3188hOq9MIjhqi5x0Od")

        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MyKey_Pq9rjt5ZFX_jpB_QF5pEarMdp18_x4")

    return true
}
```

Here is my viewController code

```
class UserLocationGm: UIViewController , GMSMapViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
        longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

    }
```

Is something missing? i.e. I'm fairly sure that I am not meant to add a MapKit View to the viewController.  Has anyone got any suggestions?

Xcode 6
Google Maps SDK: 1.9.1
Lang: Swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleMaps basic iOS demo app crash - unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019776/googlemaps-basic-ios-demo-app-crash-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: It is similar to it and I have gone through it.  However, I have done the following:  Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab. In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All. - This did not work