# Google Maps iOS made my app crash : animateToCameraPosition:camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have symbolicated my crash report from Apple, and I can see that my Google Map SDK made my app crash...

Here is my code

Contact.h :

```
@interface Contact : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contactLabel;

@end
```

Contact.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

#pragma mark - Google Map API
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 54.481151
                                                            longitude: -8.272278 zoom: 15];
    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
    GMSMarker *marker = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.title = @"Bundoran Surf Co";
    marker.snippet = @"Main Street";
    marker.map = self.mapView;
}
```

That crash on this line : `[self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];`

I don't know why...
Thanks for help, cheers !

Here is the full crash report :

```
Incident Identifier: 53F96E73-C7EC-4B25-9EA2-B7EE6BBA0989
CrashReporter Key:   45e776ed0586d581aba248bf3f23eaf42a231f2c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             BundoranSurfCo [15440]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4E406D15-DDA0-40B8-9534-E5BCEF566CCC/BundoranSurfCo.app/BundoranSurfCo
Identifier:          JardelCompany.BundoranSurfCo
Version:             1.4.1 (1.4)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-08 07:15:26.309 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-08 07:15:17.772 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18237c2d8 0x182254000 + 1213144
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193a9c0e4 0x193a94000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1823833a4 0x182254000 + 1242020
3   CoreFoundation                  0x182380154 0x182254000 + 1229140
4   CoreFoundation                  0x182282ccc 0x182254000 + 191692
5   BundoranSurfCo                  0x10003d260 -[Contact viewDidLoad] (Contact.m:24)
6   UIKit                           0x186dbcc84 0x186dac000 + 68740
7   UIKit                           0x186dbc994 0x186dac000 + 67988
8   UIKit                           0x186ef2e68 0x186dac000 + 1338984
9   UIKit                           0x186ef2b58 0x186dac000 + 1338200
10  UIKit                           0x186fba378 0x186dac000 + 2155384
11  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
12  UIKit                           0x186fba1cc 0x186dac000 + 2154956
13  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
14  UIKit                           0x186dda4e0 0x186dac000 + 189664
15  UIKit                           0x186fb9e04 0x186dac000 + 2153988
16  UIKit                           0x186df1404 0x186dac000 + 283652
17  UIKit                           0x186dda4e0 0x186dac000 + 189664
18  UIKit                           0x186df0da0 0x186dac000 + 282016
19  UIKit                           0x186daffc0 0x186dac000 + 16320
20  CoreFoundation                  0x1823342a4 0x182254000 + 918180
21  CoreFoundation                  0x182331230 0x182254000 + 905776
22  CoreFoundation                  0x182331610 0x182254000 + 906768
23  CoreFoundation                  0x18225d2d4 0x182254000 + 37588
24  GraphicsServices                0x18b94b6fc 0x18b940000 + 46844
25  UIKit                           0x186e22fac 0x186dac000 + 487340
26  BundoranSurfCo                  0x100043574 main (main.m:14)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x19411aa08 0x194118000 + 10760


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233270 0x194218000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942d116c 0x1942cc000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001941aab14 0x194148000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193269414 0x193268000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193288b88 0x193268000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193a9c3bc 0x193a94000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193285bb0 0x193268000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193285738 0x193268000 + 120632
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193a9c290 0x193a94000 + 33424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018225d380 0x182254000 + 37760
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018b94b6f8 0x18b940000 + 46840
11  UIKit                           0x0000000186e22fa8 0x186dac000 + 487336
12  BundoranSurfCo                  0x0000000100043570 main (main.m:14)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019411aa04 0x194118000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194218c24 0x194218000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001940fde6c 0x1940ec000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001940ef998 0x1940ec000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233c78 0x194218000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cd2d8 0x1942cc000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cceec 0x1942cc000 + 3820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233c78 0x194218000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cd2d8 0x1942cc000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cceec 0x1942cc000 + 3820

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233c78 0x194218000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cd2d8 0x1942cc000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cceec 0x1942cc000 + 3820

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233c78 0x194218000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cd2d8 0x1942cc000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cceec 0x1942cc000 + 3820

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194218e0c 0x194218000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194218c84 0x194218000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182333720 0x182254000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182331674 0x182254000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018225d2d0 0x182254000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001822af358 0x182254000 + 373592
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000182c68364 0x182c20000 + 295780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfdc4 0x1942cc000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfd20 0x1942cc000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942ccef4 0x1942cc000 + 3828

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194218e0c 0x194218000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194218c84 0x194218000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182333720 0x182254000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182331674 0x182254000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018225d2d0 0x182254000 + 37584
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181d3e890 0x181ca0000 + 649360
6   Foundation                      0x000000018327ddb4 0x183188000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfdc4 0x1942cc000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfd20 0x1942cc000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942ccef4 0x1942cc000 + 3828

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233c78 0x194218000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cd2d8 0x1942cc000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cceec 0x1942cc000 + 3820

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194233498 0x194218000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182339124 0x182254000 + 938276
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfdc4 0x1942cc000 + 15812
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942cfd20 0x1942cc000 + 15648
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001942ccef4 0x1942cc000 + 3828

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001740fea37
    x4: 0x0000000193289dfd   x5: 0x000000016fdd33f0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  .........
```

Comment: what was the error you received

Comment: It happens when self.mapView is nil. in the nib/Storyborad file, the GMSMapView should be of UIView not MKMapView

Comment: @Nina It was already in UIView ! Maybe I had to use <GMSMapViewDelegate> in Contact.h ?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit).. That doesn't crash on my iPhone ... Maybe because I didn't use < GMSMapViewDelegate> ???

Comment: @xcode_Dev you said you have symbolicated the crash report, edit your question and provide that. Your issue is impossible to resolve without it. Telling us "an error happened" is pointless

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't set delegate, worked fine for me. @xcode_Dev

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Edited with crash report ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've to follow this URL : [GoogleMaps basic iOS demo app crash - unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019776/googlemaps-basic-ios-demo-app-crash-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

But I've made this for the project & target setting, do you think it will be fine  :
[image]
[image]