# How to test iOS app like iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, app-store-connect

I want to put my app online in **AppStore**, but **ItunesConnect** finds crash. When I test on Xcode it works fine, no crash. I symbolicated the **crash log**, but I would like to have the same result like **ItunesConnect** : crash.

Does **ItunesConnect** have special **configuration** for testing app ?
Maybe I have to change some **parameters** in **Xcode** ?

Thanks for your help!

Crashlog :

```
Incident Identifier: 16DC5C30-0DCB-47D3-863B-9AE9E887DF78
CrashReporter Key:   45e776ed0586d581aba248bf3f23eaf42a231f2c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             BundoranSurfCo [3413]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/19330ECC-7A30-4453-BCBD-E7841A50CD4F/BundoranSurfCo.app/BundoranSurfCo
Identifier:          JardelCompany.BundoranSurfCo
Version:             1.5.1 (1.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-18 07:34:27.773 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-18 07:29:41.671 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185bec2d8 0x185ac4000 + 1213144
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19730c0e4 0x197304000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185bf33a4 0x185ac4000 + 1242020
3   CoreFoundation                  0x185bf0154 0x185ac4000 + 1229140
4   CoreFoundation                  0x185af2ccc 0x185ac4000 + 191692
5   BundoranSurfCo                  0x100024f78 -[Contact viewDidLoad] (Contact.m:24)
6   UIKit                           0x18a62cc84 0x18a61c000 + 68740
7   UIKit                           0x18a62c994 0x18a61c000 + 67988
8   UIKit                           0x18a762e68 0x18a61c000 + 1338984
9   UIKit                           0x18a762b58 0x18a61c000 + 1338200
10  UIKit                           0x18a82a378 0x18a61c000 + 2155384
11  UIKit                           0x18a661404 0x18a61c000 + 283652
12  UIKit                           0x18a82a1cc 0x18a61c000 + 2154956
13  UIKit                           0x18a661404 0x18a61c000 + 283652
14  UIKit                           0x18a64a4e0 0x18a61c000 + 189664
15  UIKit                           0x18a829e04 0x18a61c000 + 2153988
16  UIKit                           0x18a661404 0x18a61c000 + 283652
17  UIKit                           0x18a64a4e0 0x18a61c000 + 189664
18  UIKit                           0x18a660da0 0x18a61c000 + 282016
19  UIKit                           0x18a61ffc0 0x18a61c000 + 16320
20  CoreFoundation                  0x185ba42a4 0x185ac4000 + 918180
21  CoreFoundation                  0x185ba1230 0x185ac4000 + 905776
22  CoreFoundation                  0x185ba1610 0x185ac4000 + 906768
23  CoreFoundation                  0x185acd2d4 0x185ac4000 + 37588
24  GraphicsServices                0x18f1bb6fc 0x18f1b0000 + 46844
25  UIKit                           0x18a692fac 0x18a61c000 + 487340
26  BundoranSurfCo                  0x10002b2a4 main (main.m:14)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x19798aa08 0x197988000 + 10760
```

Comment: ItunesConnect might be giving you some crash logs, what are they?

Comment: @VinayJain Updated with crashlog. Here is my post for line 24 with Contact View : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523844/google-maps-sdk-crash-on-itunesconnect-test-not-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to test your application on all architectures like armv7, arm64 etc.
I have seen a few third-party codes not supporting particular architectures, or combination of architecture and OS versions. SKSTableView is one of the examples that has been reported to be crashing with iOS 7 and arm64 architecture.
Make sure this is not the case with you.

Additionally, integrate Crash reporting APIs to be sure to get a report even when Apple Reviewers are testing, that way, you get the version and device information on which it crashed...

Things will be easier to ask and answer... ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the architecture. I've seen on the iTunesConnect crash log they use the same architecture like me :(

Comment: Does it also mention iOS version it as tested on?

Comment: Yes, and I use the same ... ^^

Comment: Does your code have Contact.h and Contact.m? If yes, can you post it? Also, are you using Google Map and/or Facebook Integration?

Comment: Yes, please have a look on this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523844/google-maps-sdk-crash-on-itunesconnect-test-not-xcode/30525937#30525937

Comment: Does your facebook integration provide 'Like' functionality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79106/discussion-between-mayur-deshmukh-and-viny76).